# nginx rewrite for drupal

Tags: 7, uri

I have installed **Nginx** and I have a Drupal site installed in a sub folder.
I also have a directory in `/drupalpath/sites/default/files/books/` that stored some PDF in it.
I configure my nginx like this:

```
location /drupalpath {
    rewrite ^/drupalpath/(.*)$ /drupalpath/index.php?q=$1 last;
}
```

and it works nice.
But my problem is that the PDFs in `/drupalpath/sites/default/files/books/` affected this rule and when I click to download my books it send 404 Error because this rule.
My question is that how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location ~ \.pdf$ {
  try_files $uri =404;
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be nice, maybe just one sentence, about why this solution would work.

Comment: Directive try_files meets the requirements of the questioner. See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files for details.